# Multi await Task.Run handle

Tags: c#, windows, async-await

I have write 2 normal function (long task function) and want to call the function async. So the below code is here

```
Public async void AsyncTask()
        {
            Form MainForm = await Task.Run(() => CreateAppForm());
            DataTable[] MasterTables = await Task.Run(() => CreateTables());
            // How to write code for below task run complete and go to next step ?
        }

        public DataTable[] CreateTables()
        {
            // Below code is create datatable from SQL DataTable
            DataTable [] MasterTables;
            return MasterTables;
        }

        public Form CreateAppForm ()
        {
            Form masterForm= new Form();
            // write some long task code 
            return masterForm;

        }
```

I want CreateTables and CreateForm run at same time (Parallel) and the main Thread need to wait the above function run complete. Can I know how to handle it ?

Thank you .

Comment: if you're talking to a single RDBMS, concurrency isn't necessarily going to help you here...

Comment: Hi Marc, It's not single RDBMS, above is just a example, which I want to make new form and datatable at the same time, instead of run the function sequentially.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a single RDBMS?

Comment: On a side note if this isn't run as an eventhandler I would advise you to use `public async Task AsyncTask()` instead of `public async void AsyncTask()`

Comment: Yes. just want to make a function , which want to create form and do another task (e.g. create datatable at the same time) without run sequentially

Comment: Hi Knoop: I have tried to do async task , but if I use into createform function, I don't know how to return the form on async task function.
E.g.
 public virtual async Task <Form> CreateAppForm ()
        {
            Form masterForm= new Form();
            // write some long task code 
            return masterForm;

        }
I will get error.

Comment: In this example if you change `public Form CreateAppForm()` to `public Task<Form> CreateAppForm()` you would have to change the `return` to `return Task.FromResult(masterForm)` since at the moment you're not really using tasks anywhere in that function

Comment: Hi Knoop, Thanks for your advise, I will try it , Thank you

Comment: @Knoop Returning a `Task` and using `Task.FromResult` is only useful if you *might* actually be returning an incomplete `Task` (for example, if you might have the value in cache, but need to await an I/O request if not). If the only return value possible will only ever come from `Task.FromResult`, then returning a `Task` is valueless overhead.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Ofcourse, my comment was not about whether this is a good idea. Just stating that IF you want to do it like that, you have to do it like this to prevent the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Thread.WaitAll(); See [Thread.WaitAll Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething1()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething2()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething3())
};    
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
// Code below this line will execute after all asyncs have completed 
var x = "test";
```

EDIT: Now storing the return of the async method to variables;

```
string return1 = string.Empty;
string return2 = string.Empty;

var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => return1 = "First return"),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => return2 = "Second return"),
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine(return1); // First return
Console.WriteLine(return2); // Second return
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, but I need to get return value from DoSomething1,DoSomething2..etc
also, is this async is not suitable on this case?

Comment: @Michael `await Task.WhenAll`  for that

Comment: See edited response.. you have to adjust to your needs, but variable scoping will help you in this case..

Comment: [This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) explains that you should use `Task.Run` unless you have specific reasons for using `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: This could very, very dangerous if the variable set inside the task is not threadsafe! Better have the tasks return a variable! Also, since we are dealing with a winforms app using WaitAll as opposed to the nonblocking WhenAll is a no-go because of possible deadlocks!

Comment: Hi Peter, Gabriel, Bruno :
Thanks for all comment, I will study for it. For my goal, I want to make run the two time consume task (one is create the big form ) and other is get data from remote site. concurrently. So. it seem Garbriel  example is seem what I want, but I have learn another method from Bruno Farias, I will try for both, Thank you

Comment: @PeterBons good catch, I didn't realize WaitAll was thread blocking, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @BrunoFarias You should almost never use `Task.WaitAll` - it's blocking synchronously and is a recipe for problems.

Answer (score 3):

Putting aside the issue of whether this will actually achieve what you want...

If you want to start a `Task`, you just create it. When you want the result of the `Task`, you `await` it. So split up the lines where you start the `Task` and when you `await` it:

```
public async Task AsyncTask()
{
    //start the Tasks so they run concurrently
    var mainFormTask = Task.Run(() => CreateAppForm());
    var createTableTask = Task.Run(() => CreateTables());

    //await the Tasks and get the results
    Form MainForm = await mainFormTask;
    DataTable[] MasterTables = await createTableTask;
}
```

But again, I'm not entirely sure if that's really a great idea (or will do anything meaningful) in this specific scenario.

Comment: Hi Garbriel : Thanks, so I don't need use Task.WhenAll () ?
and I can continue to write on after , DataTable[] MasterTables = await createTableTask; ?
Thank you

Comment: Using `WaitAll` or `WhenAll` is helpful when you just need to know that the tasks are done, but it complicates getting the results back, because you then have to go into the array of tasks to get the results. Either way will work, but if you have very few tasks, it's easier to just use separate variables for them.

Comment: Note, that using separate `await` statements will run the tasks back-to-back, not in parallel. `Task.WhenAll` would be needed to run the tasks in parallel (assuming they can run in parallel).

Comment: @xxbbcc That's not true. You should try it :)

Comment: @xxbbcc tasks are started as soon as `Task.Run` is called. So they will run parallel. Only the await is sequential here.

Comment: @PeterBons I guess both of you are right. After seeing your comments I started thinking about this more and I see why I was incorrect - the tasks were started separate from the awaits - so the current setup is basically a long-winded WhenAll().